# Writing unit test for ServletFilter is not getting servlet response content

Tags: java, spring, servlets, servlet-filters

I work on a set of SpringBoot services.  We have a ServletFilter that uses ESAPI to HTML-encode the request, to prevent cross-site scripting.  I realized there was a change I needed to make in how it encodes the data.  I think I made the correct change, but I'm having trouble writing a unit test to verify this.  I may be confused about what I should expect to happen.  I wrote a simple test that uses the Spring MockHttpServlet{Request,Response} classes.

All I want to verify is that the content from the servlet response has the expected value.

The test method currently looks like this:

```
@Test
public void protectAgainstDoubleEncoding() throws Exception {
    String input   = "{\"foo\": \"bar AT&amp;T foo\"}";
    
    MockHttpServletRequest  servletRequest  = new MockHttpServletRequest();
    servletRequest.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    servletRequest.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    servletRequest.setContent(input.getBytes());
    MockHttpServletResponse servletResponse = new MockHttpServletResponse();
    servletResponse.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    servletResponse.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    
    MockFilterConfig config = new MockFilterConfig(); 
    MockFilterChain filterChain = new MockFilterChain();
    xssFilter.init(config);
    
    xssFilter.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse, filterChain);

    assertThat(servletResponse.getContentAsString()).isEqualTo(input);
}
```

I'm not showing the code of "xssFilter" at this point.

When I run this test, the "getContentAsString()" call returns an empty string.

Comment: Where is the relation between `MockHttpServletResponse` and `MockHttpServletRequest`?  Right now the way code is, it seems `servletResponse` has no information or `servletRequest`?

Comment: I don't understand the question.  Both the request and response are passed to the "doFilter" method.  I don't know what "servletResponse has no information or servletRequest" means.